# React Three Fiber object is transparent

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a tube object (camera lens) and i can't make it not to be transparent.
"meshStandardMaterial" is not doing anything with an object. Im trying to recreate this -> https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/camera-lens-5becb229622042299aefb9f70f2a16f1

```
export default function Lens() {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/models/lens.glb')
  const props = useTexture({
    map: '/lens/textures/blinn2_baseColor.png',
    metallicMap: '/lens/textures/blinn2_metallicRoughness.png',
    normalMap: '/lens/textures/blinn2_normal.png'
  })

  return (
    <group dispose={null}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.camera_lens_blinn2_0.geometry} material={materials.blinn2} scale={0.40} />
      <meshStandardMaterial {...props} />
    </group>
  )
}
```